# How do I make Bottom Sheet show on viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

I want a bottom sheet to show on a scene with Google map on `viewDidLoad()` but the only bottom sheet example I found on the `material.io` website gets triggered with a button.
How do I use `MDCBottomSheetController` to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@stone-cold See below-mentioned code.

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bottomSheet = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: viewController)

        // Present the bottom sheet
        present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

See more details here https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/BottomSheet